# Using inherited constructor in Solidity >=0.5.0

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.5.x, constructor, solidity-0.6.x, solidity-0.7.x

I want to use a contract inherit from another contract and use the parent constructor after using another commands in inherited constructor. So I wrote:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.10;

contract A {
    constructor(uint x) public {
        //some commands
    }
}
contract B is A {
    contructor(uint x) public {
        //another commands that must be executed first

        //calling A constructor with x parameter:
        A(x);
        //or:
        super.constructor(x); //has error
        //or ???
    }
}
```

If I use the first solution it assumes that it should cast x variable as A contract. another solutions result error.

If we use `A(x)` as the B constructor modifier there is no way to run the parent commands after the inherited commands.

```
    ...
    contructor(uint x) public A(x) {
        //another commands that must be executed first
    }
    ...
```

finally I was forced to use a secondary function as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.10;

contract A {
    constructor(uint x) public {
        p(x);
    }
    function p(uint x) internal {
        //some commands
    }
}
contract B is A {
    contructor(uint x) public {
        //another commands that must be executed first

        //calling A constructor with x parameter:
        A.p(x);
        //or:
        super.p(x);
    }
}
```

Is there any straight solution, so we don't need to use the secondary function?

Comment: In `contract B`, you need `contructor(uint x) A(x) {...}`, and that's it.

Comment: And BTW, you need to declare each one of the constructors either `public` or `internal`.

Comment: P.S.: Your question is a total mess, and it is rather unclear what you want to ask. For example, it starts with a broken piece of code followed by "If I use the first solution"... What "first solution"? Where exactly is there a list of solutions prior to this statement???

Comment: Note that we need some codes executed before the parent constructor code.

Comment: The first solution is `A(x);` and the second is `super.constructor(x)` that generates error.

Comment: Neither one of those is a valid syntax in Solidity.

Comment: Note that if you want code executed prior to the constructor of a base class, then that code must reside in the base class. This is the case in every OO language (i.e., not specific to Solidity).

Comment: No, in some languages (like C++) you can use some commands before you call the parent function. It is also possible for non-constructor functions in Solidity.

Comment: It's not possible to execute a constructor without executing super class constructor, in any language I know, including Solidity and C++.

Answer (score 0):

Having contract A

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract A {
    uint public a;
    constructor(uint _a) internal {
        a = _a;
    }
}

...
```

you can either pass a constant argument with this syntax

```
...

contract B is A(1) {
    constructor() public {}
}
```

or you can pass a variable with this syntax.

```
...

contract B is A {
    constructor(uint _y) A(_y * _y) public {}
}
```

Comment: This is not applicable because I want to use the argument of `B` constructor when I want to call `A` constructor, not a constant number like 1.

Comment: @AlirezaZojaji Updated the answer which takes a variable parameter.

Comment: Now the main problem is that how I can run the parent constructor after running some commands in current constructor.

Comment: That's impossible and doesn't make sense. Constructors are only for object construction. You can separate the logic you want to call into another function.